# Performance of ClearRenderTargetView

Tags: directx11, sharpdx, wpf

While profiling GPU usage in VS2017, I've noticed a strange disproportion in performance of `ClearRenderTargetView` compared to `ClearDepthStencilView`:

[image: Profiler report screenshot]

What can cause this four-orders-of-magnitude difference?

First idea was that the `1.0f` I'm writing to the depth buffer is a special optimized value, so I've tried `0.0f` and `0.4f`, but it seem to affect nothing. Then I tried to change the clear color from `(0,0,0,1)` to `(0,0,0,0)` to no avail.

Googling for `ClearRenderTargetView performance` brings up nothing.

The only thing I can think of is that the target texture is somehow affected by the D3D9 interop it participates in:

```
private void InitRenderTarget(int width, int height) {
    var renderTargetDescr = new Texture2DDescription() {
        Width = width,
        Height = height,
        MipLevels = 1,
        ArraySize = 1,
        SampleDescription = new DxgiSampleDescription(1, 0),
        Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
        CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,

        // The following are mandatory for WPF interop:
        Format = DxgiFormat.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
        BindFlags = BindFlags.RenderTarget | BindFlags.ShaderResource,
        OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.Shared
    };
    _renderTarget = new Texture2D(_device, renderTargetDescr);
    var renderTargetViewDescr = new RenderTargetViewDescription {
        Format = renderTargetDescr.Format,
        Dimension = RenderTargetViewDimension.Texture2D
    };
    _renderTargetView = new RenderTargetView(_device, _renderTarget, renderTargetViewDescr);
}

private void SetupWpfInterop() {
    _surfaceD3D9 = _d3d9.DXDevice.GetSharedD3D9(_renderTarget).GetSurfaceLevel(0);
    _targetImage.Lock();
    _targetImage.SetBackBuffer(D3DResourceType.IDirect3DSurface9, _surfaceD3D9.NativePointer);
    _targetImage.Unlock();
}
```

But then, calls to `DrawIndexed` would likely also be affected, which doesn't seem to be the case (or I just misinterpret the profiler diagrams).

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would cause this to be so long is that there is some sort of lock the call is waiting for.  If it is then it will skew the results.  Maybe unbind it from pipeline (if it is bound, im assuming) before clearing it, see if the call results change.